# When was the last time my table was vacuumed?

Tags: postgresql

I am running Postgres 9.6. 
I have recently been reading of the importance of `VACUUM`ing in postgres. I am looking for a SQL statement that could return a list of my tables and when was the last time they were vacuumed. Does a statement like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does:

```
SELECT last_vacuum,
       last_autovacuum
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'
  AND relname = 'mytable';
```